# How to target the right ID in a modal window with Vue JS?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, axios

I am currently learning to connect a Vue JS front with a basic API built on Node.js and Express on a TodoList project using Axios.

My issue is the following:

I have already made all the connections back to the front. I set up the different requests like to add, delete or display. My problem is that I configured the "edit" button to launch a modal window, and I can not correctly target the right item (All my items are displayed.) to be able to make an edit request PATCH.

How to target the right id in my database when I click on button "Edit" to be able to edit only this id.

```
<div v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo">
        <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modification</h5>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="close"
                  data-dismiss="modal"
                  aria-label="Close"
                >
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" v-model="changeTodo" />
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-secondary"
                  data-dismiss="modal"
                >
                  Cancel
                </button>
                <button
                  v-for="todo in todos"
                  :key="todo.id"
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-primary"
                  @click="updateTodo(todo.id)"
                >
                  Modification {{ todo.id }}
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <li
          class="card-title d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between h1"
        >
          {{ todo.title }}
          <div>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm mr-2"
              data-toggle="modal"
              data-target=".modal"
            >
              Change
            </button>
```

---

```
export default {
  name: "TodoList",
  data() {
    return {
      todos: null,
      newTodo: "",
      changeTodo: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getAllTodos() {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/todos");

      this.todos = response.data;
    },
    addTodo() {
      axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/todos", {
        title: this.newTodo
      });
      this.newTodo = "";
    },
    deleteTodo(id) {
      axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/api/todos/${id}`);
    },
    updateTodo(id) {
      axios.patch(`http://localhost:4000/api/todos/${id}`, {
        title: this.changeTodo
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getAllTodos();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change v-for="todo in todos" in the button to a different name, there could be a scope issue because your parent iteration variable is called the same.

Comment: Yes, I try but with the modal window I do not have the scope of the for loop that runs above, so I make a second for loop with the same name.